# T-test for proportion: Sample not contributing to either numerator or denominator of the metric. Should I consider it?

Tags: t-test, sample-size, proportion, ab-test

Suppose let's say I am running AB test randomized on customers. Each customer in Control and Treatment group get an email with different messages. Customer can click on the email and then click on the link in the email. My metric is (clicks on the link in email)/(clicks on the email). So let's say if a customer doesn't click on the email and not contributing to either numerator or denominator of the metric, should I consider this customer in the sample size number for t-test for proportions calculation?

Comment: You will have to decide that for yourself. As you've stated it, customers who don't click on the email at all don't contribute to your metric. However, your business question may need to include those customers, in which case you should change your metric to include them.

Comment: I already have another metric which is (clicks on the email)/(emails sent) which includes those customers. So no confusion here. 

But I also want to measure (clicks on the link in email)/(clicks on the email). Couldn't find any resources around this use case.

Comment: Fair enough. I would say you should not include customers who don't click on the email in your (clicks on link / clicks on email) metric. This is a matter of your definitions (which is by no means trivial; at my workplace, we often think about these things, and sometimes re-define metrics to answer our business questions better).